# Html not view when i click on view Source on browser

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, typescript

I have a issue with my web application. I have used TypeScript, KnockoutJs and Web Api in the web application development, But when i click on view source of browser i have only get some scripts code not found any html tags. i don't understand how it has behave like that,

Please help me, How can i render its html on view source.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think Knockout.js is the issue. Please check below link:
[Knockout visible binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

Check the data-bind tag, value passed to it must be true for content to be visible.

```
<div data-bind="visible: myValues().length > 0">
    You will see this message only when 'myValues' has at least one member.
</div>
```

Comment: Actually Prabhat i can not found whole page html. But it is visible when i click on inspect element .
and when i click on view source on browser it has show only script code not html.